# Problem with Android Studio - error: cannot find symbol class Retention

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with my Andoid Studio (3.5 version). When I write a class, like this:

```
public class ExampleEnum
{
    @Retention ( RetentionPolicy.SOURCE )
    @IntDef (
            {
                    A, B, C, D, E, F
            } )
    public @interface Numbers
    {
        int A = 0;
        int B = 1;
        int C = 2;
        int D = 3;
        int E = 4;
        int F = 5;
    }
```

If I try to run my App, I always obtain the same errors: **error: cannot find symbol class Retention and** and **error: cannot find symbol class IntDef**

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Share you gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to include the following in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

And the import statement in your class would be such :

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
```

Comment: Done, no changes. If I have an other code error when I try to run my App, after I fixed it  I have not any problems and I can run my App perfectly.

Comment: Done, the same problems stills.

Comment: both intdef and retention?

Comment: Yes, both of them. If I have four classes like the example, I have the same error with the four classes.